# ZwAllocateVirtualMemory equivalent in linux

Tags: linux, memory, virtual, drivers

anybody know how the equivalent for ZwAllocateVirtualMemory in linux ? I want a linux device driver to allocate virtual address space in a process.

Comment: It should be the opposite: the user process is allocating virtual address space thru [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Comment: Right. I know that is the usual way. But do you know if it can be done the other way ? Ie driver allocating virtual memory for a process ?

Comment: No. AFAIK, virtual address space change only with `mmap`, `munmap` and some few other syscalls. I believe your driver design is not Unix-friendly.

Comment: Oh its absolutely not unix friendly. Trying to find out why windows allows a driver to allocate virtual memory in a process and *nix doesnt allow this. Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do_mmap and vm_mmap for newer kernel versions can be used to allocated virtual memory in a process from a linux driver.